# Find groups of consecutive numbers inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need an algorithm to find a sequence of numbers inside an array, with a pre-defined lenght. By example:

> Given the lenght 3 and the array:
>
> {2, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 0}
>
> the algorithmn should return the 3 sequences of {1, 2, 3} inside the
>   array.

Anyone can point a direction to how accomplish that? I am workin with Java, but I am accepting examples in any language, since I be able to translate to Java.

**UPDATE 1**

In my project, I have a large ordered sequence of a pair [date, hour] (which easily can have hundreds of itens, and I need to know how much sequences of sequential pairs I have.

**UPDATE 2**

More about the question:
Given the original array, I need get other taken inside it, each one formed by the consecutive sequences of numbers.

Comment: @Kon brutal, but yet so true.

Sort the array, then grab the first three.  The rest you can do on your own.

Comment: Ok, I add more info in the topic after I publish (don't know if you saw), explained more about what I want - I guess the first part of the topic was a little confuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working correctly now. I wish there was some way I could let you know.

This is pretty robust; it will count the occurrences of multiple sequences if they occur more than once. The `Map` actually records all sequences but only prints out those that occur more than once.

Note that the second for loop initializes `ii` to `i` and not `0`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Sequences {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] arr = {2, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 0};
        int sequenceLength = 3;

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int count;
        String str1, str2;

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - sequenceLength; i++) {
            str1 = "";
            count = 0;
            for (int a = i; a < i + sequenceLength; a++) {
                    str1 += "" + arr[a];
                }
            if (map.get(str1) != null) {
                continue;
            } else {
                map.put(str1, count);
            }
            for (int ii = i; ii <= arr.length - sequenceLength; ii++) {
                str2 = "";
                for (int a = ii; a < ii + sequenceLength; a++) {
                    str2 += "" + arr[a];
                }
                if (str1.equals(str2)) {
                    count++;
                    map.put(str1, count);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){ 
            if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed it had a problem. When `i` reaches where the first `ii` was, it will count the second position of `ii` again. The effect is compounded for further repetitions. Plus you've got your string building hardcoded. I'd add another answer with it all worked out, but the question seems to be closed now. I'm sure you've got it. :-)

Comment: Yeah, there we go. I was making it uber complicated when I didn't need to and reading your comment made me realize I was doing it in an excessively convoluted way. Thanks. :p

Comment: Yep. That's right about what I did, too. Only instead of having int count and doing a put every match, my HashMap's value was an AtomicInteger that I just got and told to incrementAndGet every match. Oh and containsKey instead of get(key) != null. Same idea though. :-)